# How to tell if app entered background on iOS14+ SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I'm writing an iOS14+ app, trying to use `.onChange(of: scenePhase)` which supposedly is the modern replacement for the app entering foreground or background.

But I receive the `.inactive` phase while a system dialog pops up (e.g. when asking for pairing a device) - that is not the same thing as the old didEnterBackground/foreground!

I currently do not do any background processing, so I do not receive a `.background` phase -- only `.inactive` and then `.active` again.  So there’s no easy way to tell the difference between the system dialog and actually going into the background.

I want to know if the user has left my app and come back.  Is that not available going forward?  I don't want to use old deprecated methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
    for: UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in 
…
}
```

Comment: @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase didn't work for me. your trick works perfect.

Comment: This indeed works where Environment scenePhase does not.  How did you figure this out?  And why doesn't  Environment scenePhase work??